# Android emulator not coming online in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to debug my Android app using the emulator, but the device won't come online.  Here is a screen capture of my Android Studio (v. 2.2.1) when I try to launch the emulator:

[image: screen capture]

I have tried all the solutions that has been provided here.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the following path:

Tools -> AVD Manager

then in the "Actions" area of the intended device click the grey downwards triangle, next select the "Wipe Data" and confirm it to restore the emulator to the so-called factory mode.

Comment: This helped me. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly close your emulator. `Go to Task Manager > Processes > Background Processes` then select `adb` click on `End Task` .
After that run your emulator. Thanks

Comment: @ChakshuMahajan  please create new emulator with 768 MB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Delete that emulator and create it again using x86 architecture CPU